# use a value from an R dataframe to normalise a column of another dataframe

Tags: r

Apologies if this has been asked before!

I have a big data set that I need to normalise. The data is in one dataframe, and the value needed for normalisation is in a different one. I've created a small example here:

```
data = data.frame(AMR = c("cfxA", "23S", "sul2"),
                  ACLOD_1 = c(347, 323, 186),
                  ACLOD_11 = c(0, 90, 0), 
                  ACLOD_12 = c(74, 298, 0))

scg = data.frame(gene = "dnaG", 
                 ACLOD_1 = 683,
                 ACLOD_11 = 789,
                 ACLOD_12 = 556)
```

What I need to do is divide the values in "data" by the corresponding value in "scg"; i.e. divide the values in the ACLOD_1 column (347, 323, 186) by 683 so that I get 0.51, 0.47 and 0.27, while the values in ACLOD_11 would be divided by 789, etc.

I've previously managed this by separating out each column of the data and working on it that way, but as I will likely have more than 1,000 columns in total to work on I need to work out a different way - so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the columns of interest (assuming we need the columns except the first), use `Map` to divide the corresponding selected columns from 'data' and 'scg' and assign it back to the 'data' columns

```
nm1 <- names(data)[-1]
data[nm1] <- Map(`/`,data[nm1], scg[nm1])
```

---

Or with vectorized

```
data[nm1] <- data[nm1]/scg[nm1][col(data[nm1])]
```

Or using `sweep`

```
data[nm1] <- sweep(data[nm1], 2, unlist(scg[nm1]), `/`)
```

Comment: Thank-you! - works for the example dataframe, however when I try it on my actual data it just says "Error in `[.data.frame`(scg, nm1) : undefined columns selected"?

Comment: @Maho Do you have different column names in `scg` and 'data'`  I assumed that you have similar column names

Comment: @Maho if the columns are in the same order.  Then you don't need the names.  YOu can just do `data[-1] <- Map(`/`, data[-1], scg[-1])`